# How to batch-empty farm tiles from wrong irrigation?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

I have a lot of farm tiles. I accidentally filled them with the wrong (polluted) water.

How can I empty them without clicking on every single tile?
Is there something like "Empty all wrong irrigation"?

And how can I remove the little bottles left on every tile after emptying the wrong irrigation? (I have not found a way to sweep them from the ground like every other object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to mass empty farm tiles. You could deconstruct and rebuild them, but this requires a lot more time and labour from your duplicants.

To remove the water bottles left behind after emptying them, you need a bottle emptier. Build the bottle emptier over a suitable area and your dupes will move them into it, emptying them into the space below. Sweeping the area with the bottles will force dupes to do this more quickly.

You can also select a bottle and select empty. This is faster but will cause dupes to empty the bottle where it is, leaving water on the floor.

Comment: My version doesn't support "bottle emptier". I think, I should upgrade soon .-)

Comment: After the upgrade, everthiny works as you wrote. Thanks!